# Error compiling program with Address Sanitizer

Tags: gcc, address-sanitizer

I am attempting to compile a program ([tarantool](https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool)) with Address Sanitizer (ASan) and I run into the following error:

```
/home/tarantool/src/fiber.c:123:2: error: implicit declaration of function '__sanitizer_start_switch_fiber' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        ASAN_START_SWITCH_FIBER(asan_state, 1,
```

I am unable to figure out the cause of this issue. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to tags you are using GCC. Fiber interface has only been implemented in Clang [this summer](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/commit/b0477747dfa8a9706f2c902e877e616aca51e06f) and merged to yet-to-be-released GCC 7 in [November](https://www.mail-archive.com/gcc-patches@gcc.gnu.org/msg152008.html). So it seems you should either switch to Clang or wait until GCC 7 is released (or use pre-release version).

As a side note you may report this issue to tarantool developers so that they check for compiler version and report errors in a friendlier manner.